# Properly extend stream.Transform class with TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, tsc, typescript3.0

I have this code:

```
import * as stream from 'stream';    

export class JSONParser extends stream.Transform {

  lastLineData = '';
  objectMode = true;

  constructor() {
    super();

  }

  transform(chunk, encoding, cb) {

    let data = String(chunk);
    if (this.lastLineData) {
      data = this.lastLineData + data;
    }

    let lines = data.split('\n');
    this.lastLineData = lines.splice(lines.length - 1, 1)[0];

    lines.forEach(l => {
      try {
        // l might be an empty string; ignore if so
        l && this.push(JSON.parse(l));
      }
      catch (err) {
        // noop
      }
    });

    cb();

  }

  flush(cb) {
    if (this.lastLineData) {
      try {
        this.push(JSON.parse(this.lastLineData));
      }
      catch (err) {
        // noop
      }
    }
    this.lastLineData = '';
    cb();
  }


}
```

the **problem** is that the TS typings don't recognize the (prototype) methods. Am I extending the Transform class incorrectly?

Here is the problem:

[image]

Note that this is correct:

```
import * as stream from 'stream';

//////////////////////////////////////////////////

export interface IParsedObject {
  [index: string]: any
}

export const createParser = function () {

  let lastLineData = '';

  return new stream.Transform({

    objectMode: true,

    transform(chunk: any, encoding: string, cb: Function) {

      let data = String(chunk);
      if (lastLineData) {
        data = lastLineData + data;
      }

      let lines = data.split('\n');
      lastLineData = lines.splice(lines.length - 1, 1)[0];

      lines.forEach(l => {
        try {
          // l might be an empty string; ignore if so
          l && this.push(JSON.parse(l));
        }
        catch (err) {
          // noop
        }
      });

      cb();

    },

    flush(cb: Function) {
      if (lastLineData) {
        try {
          this.push(JSON.parse(lastLineData));
        }
        catch (err) {
          // noop
        }
      }
      lastLineData = '';
      cb();
    }
  });

};
```

but that above class does not seem to work the same.

Comment: The need to re-specify the parameter types when you override a method is [this TypeScript issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23911).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it seems to work now, I had to pass the constructor options to `super()`, so it becomes `super({objectMode:true})`,

```
export class JSONParser extends stream.Transform {

  lastLineData = '';

  constructor() {
    super({objectMode: true});

  }

  _transform(chunk: any, encoding: string, cb: Function) {

    let data = String(chunk);
    if (this.lastLineData) {
      data = this.lastLineData + data;
    }

    let lines = data.split('\n');
    this.lastLineData = lines.splice(lines.length - 1, 1)[0];

    lines.forEach(l => {
      try {
        // l might be an empty string; ignore if so
        l && this.push(JSON.parse(l));
      }
      catch (err) {
        // noop
      }
    });

    cb();

  }

  flush(cb: Function) {
    if (this.lastLineData) {
      try {
        this.push(JSON.parse(this.lastLineData));
      }
      catch (err) {
        // noop
      }
    }
    this.lastLineData = '';
    cb();
  }

  _flush(cb: Function) {
    if (this.lastLineData) {
      try {
        this.push(JSON.parse(this.lastLineData));
      }
      catch (err) {
        // noop
      }
    }
    this.lastLineData = '';
    cb();
  }

}
```

the only question remaining is whether I should be implementing `_flush()` or `flush()`, I am not sure...I implemented both for now...

Comment: The stream API has thorough documentation. You can find the methods necessary to implement [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_implementers), and you can find specific details about implementing `Transform` streams [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream).

Comment: @JakeHolzinger not extensive enough, doesn't show whether transform should be implementing _flush() or flush(), if you can link to that or prove it to be one way or another, then you get at least 10 points. I like the inconsistency of Transform vs Writable. First of all it should be called Transformable, but that's not important. More importantly, it if you extend the Writable class you implement `write` not `_write`. But apparently with Transform if you extend that you need to implement `_transform`, not `transform`. Some inconsistency AFAICT.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger furthermore, the TypeScript typings don't seem to work for extending stream.Transform, which was therefore not providing reassuring feedback for this.

Comment: The distinction is in how you implement the stream. If you use the simplified constructor, then you implement methods without an underscore prefix. If you extend the class, then you implement methods with an underscore prefix. Extending the `Writable` class calls for implementing `writable._write(chunk, encoding, callback)` so I'm not sure where you got that information. The stream APIs are very consistent and very well documented in my opinion. I've added an answer that goes more in depth, but the basic concept described above is true for all stream implementations.

Comment: using the constructor like that would be far less performant, that's why I wanted to use the prototype methods.

Comment: The methods implemented when extending the class are prototype methods, they're just intended to be called internally. To prove my point here is the default implementation of [`transform._transform(chunk, encoding, callback)`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_transform.js#L164) for reference, it just generates an error since it is intended to be overridden. The simplified constructor does [attach the method directly to the object](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_transform.js#L129), which is less performant.

Comment: the constructor will get called for every instance

Answer (score 6):

In your screenshot you are attempting to extend the `Transform` class, but you are not implementing the correct method, you should implement `transform._transform(chunk, encoding, callback)`, then typescript will automatically infer the required types. Since `transform.transform(chunk, encoding, callback)` does not exist on the `Transform` type typescript has no types to use for inference so the compiler generates a warning.

In your code example you choose to use the "simplified" `Transform` constructor. The constructor takes a set of options that allows you to define the necessary transformation methods without explicitly extending the class. These options opt for a non-underscore prefixed naming convention, but they are equivalent to the underscore prefixed methods when extending the class. Since you used the correct name for the method here the types were able to be inferred.

---

The `Transform` API calls for the implementation of three methods, those methods are outlined [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_implementers).

There are two ways to implement a `Transform` stream:

1. Extending the `Transform` class
2. Using the `Transform` constructor
   options.

The two methods are outlined [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_implementing_a_transform_stream) (an example for extending the class in pre ES6 environments is included).

---

When implementing a `Transform` stream only one method must be implemented:

1. `transform._transform(chunk, encoding, callback)`

The other two methods are optional and can be implemented if the use case calls for it:

1. `transform._flush(callback)`
2. `writable._final(callback)`

---

I've gone ahead and outlined the documented `Transform` methods below, highlighting some areas that may be of interest.

### [`transform._flush(callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_flush_callback)

> **This function MUST NOT be called by application code directly. It
>   should be implemented by child classes, and called by the internal
>   Readable class methods only.**
>
> In some cases, a transform operation may need to emit an additional
>   bit of data at the end of the stream. For example, a zlib compression
>   stream will store an amount of internal state used to optimally
>   compress the output. When the stream ends, however, that additional
>   data needs to be flushed so that the compressed data will be complete.
>
> **Custom Transform implementations *may* implement the transform._flush()
>   method.** This will be called when there is no more written data to be
>   consumed, but before the 'end' event is emitted signaling the end of
>   the Readable stream.
>
> Within the transform._flush() implementation, the readable.push()
>   method may be called zero or more times, as appropriate. The callback
>   function must be called when the flush operation is complete.
>
> **The transform._flush() method is prefixed with an underscore because
>   it is internal to the class that defines it, and should never be
>   called directly by user programs.**

### [`transform._transform(chunk, encoding, callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_transform_chunk_encoding_callback)

> **This function MUST NOT be called by application code directly. It
>   should be implemented by child classes, and called by the internal
>   Readable class methods only.**
>
> **All Transform stream implementations must provide a _transform()
>   method to accept input and produce output.** The transform._transform()
>   implementation handles the bytes being written, computes an output,
>   then passes that output off to the readable portion using the
>   readable.push() method.
>
> The transform.push() method may be called zero or more times to
>   generate output from a single input chunk, depending on how much is to
>   be output as a result of the chunk.
>
> It is possible that no output is generated from any given chunk of
>   input data.
>
> The callback function must be called only when the current chunk is
>   completely consumed. The first argument passed to the callback must be
>   an Error object if an error occurred while processing the input or
>   null otherwise. If a second argument is passed to the callback, it
>   will be forwarded on to the readable.push() method. In other words the
>   following are equivalent:

```
transform.prototype._transform = function(data, encoding, callback) {
  this.push(data);
  callback();
};

transform.prototype._transform = function(data, encoding, callback) {
  callback(null, data);
};
```

> **The transform._transform() method is prefixed
>   with an underscore because it is internal to the class that defines
>   it, and should never be called directly by user programs.**
>
> transform._transform() is never called in parallel; streams implement
>   a queue mechanism, and to receive the next chunk, callback must be
>   called, either synchronously or asynchronously.

### [`writable._final(callback)`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_final_callback)

> **The _final() method must not be called directly. It may be implemented
>   by child classes, and if so, will be called by the internal Writable
>   class methods only.**
>
> This optional function will be called before the stream closes,
>   delaying the 'finish' event until callback is called. This is useful
>   to close resources or write buffered data before a stream ends.